# How to swap values in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

This piece of codes segment fault on me, any idea why? `allButtons` is a `NSMutableArray`, it contains 3 objects, `a=0, b=1`, a and b are `int` type

```
 if(a != -1 && b!= -1){
    //Swap index in "allButtons"
    id tempA = [allButtons objectAtIndex:a];
    id tempB = [allButtons objectAtIndex:b];
    [allButtons replaceObjectAtIndex:a withObject:tempB]; //Seg fault here?????
    [allButtons replaceObjectAtIndex:b withObject:tempA];
    needLoad = false;
    [self setUpButtons];
 }
```

EDIT:

```
 NSMutableArray *allButtons = //fetch the array from Coredata. This work since I display the data onto the screen, plus, [allButtons count] return 3, and a=0, b=1
 f(a != -1 && b!= -1){
    //Swap index in "allButtons"
    [allButtons exchangeObjectAtIndex:a withObjectAtIndex:b];
    needLoad = false;
    [self setUpButtons];
 }
```

Comment: It may be helpful to post the actual error message, if possible. It would probably also be helpful to post the class declaration so that we can see whether allButtons is a property, and if so, what its memory management semantics are, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just because you have said

```
NSMutableArray *allbuttons = // something
```

doesn't mean that it is definitely an NSMutableArray, it just means that the compiler thinks that it will be a NSMutableArray.

If it's from CoreData, it's probably just an `NSArray` so the method calls you are trying won't work - you'll get unrecongnised selector or something like that.

You will have to convert it to a mutable array first

```
NSArray *coreData = // core data call

// Create a mutable copy
// NB This means that you are now working on a copy, not the original :)
NSMutableArray *allButtons = [coreData mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Or just NSMutableArray *allButtons = [coreData mutablecopy];

Answer (score 22):

The first call to `replaceObjectAtIndex:` will release the old object (`tempA`), but that shouldn't cause a seg fault. As @Zoran mentioned try logging the `retainCount` for tempA and verify its count.

Also for swapping elements in an array, you should use [`exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:) instead of `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject`. It's supported from iPhone 2.0.

Comment: I try `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex` and this is what I got `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3a35a30'`. BTW, `recountCount` return back 3.

Comment: what version of the iPhone SDK are you using? Also, please post the code where you are creating the `NSMutableArray`, and using `exchangeObject..`

Comment: looks like `_PFArray` is a subclass of `NSArray` and does not have the methods of `NSMutableArray`. You might have a make a new object that is of the type `NSMutableArray` and initialize it with the existing array. `NSMutableArray *theObject = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:allButtons]` and then call `exchangeObjectAt..` on `theObject`. (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:i12_AOCFOTAJ:ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs300/___p_f_array_8h-source.html+/search%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3D%2Bsite:ericasadun.com%2B_PFArray&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Comment: that also explains why `replaceObjectAtIndex` was seg-faulting before.

Comment: that actually fixed it, how do I store it back to `allButtons`?

Answer (score 2):

`tempA` is going to be released when you call the first `replaceObjectAtIndex`. Keep that in mind when calling this... I have no idea why releasing `tempA` would seg fault for you, examine what its `dealloc` does perhaps.

Check the retain count of `tempA` to verify that it is indeed dealloc-ed (not simply released) by the call to `replaceObjectAtIndex` like so:

```
id tempA = [allButtons objectAtIndex:a];
NSLog(@"retain count for tempA: %i", [tempA retainCount]);
```

If you see a retain count of 1 at this level, then your object `tempA` is being dealloc-ed by the call to `replaceObjectAtIndex`

Comment: `recountCount` return back 3.

Comment: Are you calling this from the main thread or a secondary thread? If you're calling it from a secondary thread, did you create an auto-release pool?

Answer (score 0):

Please read and understand the Cocoa rules on [object ownership](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).  Note that you have not claimed ownership over the objects referenced by tempA and tempB and you must therefore heed the following:

> A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method it was received in ... (**although you must also take care if you modify an object from which you received another object**). That method may also safely return the object to its invoker.

Basically, the line:

```
[allButtons replaceObjectAtIndex:a withObject:tempB];
```

May cause tempA to be deallocated.  This means that the subsequent line will cause allButtons to send a retain message to an invalid object, hence the seg fault.  To fix the problem, you need to retain tempA before the swap and release it or autorelease it after.

NB it's wise to forget about retain counts.  Unless you are fully aware of the implementation of all objects that touch your objects, you cannot make any assumptions about what the retain count of an object is.  For instance, there's no rule that says that the implementation of NSMutableArray will only ever retain its elements once.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method pass the appropritate index

```
exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:
```